# Should i mine with gaming pc?

Tags: mining-hardware, mining-reward

i want to ask should i start mining with my gaming pc spec:
(cpu) i7-6700K 4gh
(gpu) 1060 3gb
and will i get more bit than wasted power?
and what miners you use ?

Comment: oh, thanks, but what program to use for mining ?

Comment: bfgminer and cgminer are two of the most popular ones. But someone who knows better than me may recommend you some others.

Answer (score 1):

BTC mining is not a real option anymore for home miners. It's not profitable as it was before. The only way to be profitable with BTC mining these days is custom made computers that are made for BTC mining.

The most people with a normal or gaming pc lose money instead of making profit when mining BTC.